# How to invalidate with custom cache policy

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

**Context**

I have a distribution where I added the host to the cache policy

These 2 domains point to the same distribution:

- [www.site1.com/pageA](http://www.site1.com/pageA)
- [www.site2.com/pageA](http://www.site2.com/pageA)

these 2 hosts have their respective cache entry, In this setup, I have a custom origin response lambda on edge that will return different content base on the host.

**The question:**

I'm use to invalidate based on the path ex: /pageA

how should I format my invalidation if I want to only invalidate pageA for site1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to invalidate by domain.
Cloudfront invalidation is by path only.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Comment: ok thank for the answer. I was assuming that it was possible, for me it would make sense to have the options.

I think  we may  try to change the request object path in a viewer request lambda

so that www.site1.com/pageA cache will be

/host-site1/pageA

instead of 

/pageA

so we will be able to clear the cache base on host

Comment: Yes I think that is a good workaround for your use case.